# How do I keep my conservatory roof drain clean?

Tags: roof, roofing

Our conservatory roof is made from [Everlite](http://www.everliteconservatoryroofs.co.uk/).  The problem we have is that where the roof runs into the drain is constantly filling up with soil, stones and moss.  I have no idea where it's all coming from, but my question is: is there a way to prevent this?  It's very difficult to properly clear out the gap (as it's not very big), and the clogging causes the water to back up on the roof.

Comment: Can you post a picture?  Understanding where the soil and stones are coming from would be the first step to understand how to prevent the soil and stones from building up?

Comment: The roof is exactly the same as that in the link (I assume they all look the same).  Any debris building up must be coming from the house roof.  My guess was that it's a combination of rain and wind blowing moss and dirt off the main roof and bird dropping stuff directly onto the conservatory.  I suppose the question was not so much of how to stop the stuff getting onto the conservatory roof, but how to stop it clogging the gap into the drain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are devices called gutter guards that allow the water to enter the gutter/drain but the debris continues over the gutter and off the edge of the roof.  Not sure if you could get one of those for your conservatory roof but you might try looking into them.

Comment: I've just had a look at this on Google, and to be honest, I'm not sure it would work for the conservatory roof.  However, while I was looking I came across Gutter Guard Foam!  I'm going to give that a try - thanks!